# NSURLSession download task grows memory in debug with default session config

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I've got an app that downloads files using `NSURLSession` on iOS 7 and later.  I start the task like this:

```
//property declared: @property (retain) NSURLSession *session;

NSString *addr = @"http://www.example.com/path/to/nontrivial/file.dat";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:addr];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
[[self.session downloadTaskWithRequest:request] resume];
```

In the completion handler (`URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:`), I move the file to my application data folder and call `invalidateAndCancel` on the session. In the progress handler (`didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:`), I simply log the progress.

As this runs in debug, memory usage increases quickly, to the tune of a few times the amount of data that has been downloaded. If I do it in a background task, though, memory usage is constant.

Is it bad to use the default session configuration with a download task? Is there some kind of cache property that I should be setting? What's going on here?

**Update:** As far as I can tell, this only happens when the debugger is attached. When I launch it in the simulator without the debugger, I don't see any memory usage increase in Activity Monitor.

**Update 2:** This appears to have been fixed in iOS 8.3. Yay!

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I've dug a little deeper and found that memory usage (as reported by calling host_statistics on the device) does not actually increase. It seems that whatever is reporting memory usage to Xcode/to the process responsible for killing memory-hogs is broken.

Comment: @Ahti - Awesome. Time to file a radar.

Answer (score 0):

This same behavior was happening to me. It was manifesting itself via hard crashes when memory became depleted. For anyone else who's curious if they're seeing this same problem, follow these steps...

1. Open activity monitor alongside the iOS simulator, go to the memory tab and enter your app's name in the search results.
2. Run your app in the simulator via xcode. Wait until you see the process listed in activity monitor, and then queue up a download or two. Activity monitor will show the memory usage for your app ballooning out of control.
3. Stop execution of your app in xcode. Restart the app in the simulator without the aid of xcode. Wait for your app to appear in activity monitor again, and queue up a few more downloads. When you do it this time, the memory usage for your app should basically remain the same.

This was a really great observation on your part. I never would have thought to investigate this path. Thanks!

Comment: It's fixed in iOS 8.3, it appears.